# How to install APR in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apr

Apache Portable Runtime is a dependency to compile some apps.

`./configure` says that `apr-1` is needed.

How to install it on Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install libapr1 libapr1-dev
```

Comment: Where is it installed?

Comment: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtcnative-1.so

Answer (score 15):

Try this:

- `sudo apt-get install apache2-dev libapr1-dev libaprutil1-dev`
- `sudo exec $SHEL`
- `sudo service apache2 restart`

That's enough to use correctly Apache Portable Runtime and Apache Portable Runtime Utils.

Good Luck.

Comment: My thanks. Installation ```libapr1```, ```libapr1-dev``` packages (first answear) lead to build error - apr headers not found. Then I installed a ```apache2-dev``` package and build finish successfully.

Answer (score 5):

use:

```
sudo apt-get install libtcnative
```

Answer (score 3):

run the following commands

```
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt --fix-broken install
    sudo apt-get install libapr1 libapr1-dev
```